# preg_match a php string with simple or double quotes escaped inside

Tags: php, regex

I want to parse some php files containing something like this :

```
// form 1
__('some string');
// form 2
__('an other string I\'ve written with a quote');
// form 3
__('an other one
multiline');
// form 4
__("And I want to handle double quotes too !");
// form 5
__("And I want to handle double quotes too !", $second_parameter_may_happens);
```

The following regex match everything except the 2nd one

```
preg_match_all('#__\((\'|")(.*)\1(?:,.*){0,1}\)#smU', $file_content);
```

Comment: Don't use a regex, at least not one that's supposed to do everything at once. Even if you get it working in practice, the difficulty of proving that it always works and the maintainability nightmare if a change needs to be made is not worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~__\((["\'])(?<param1>(?>[^"\'\\\]+|\\\.|(?!\1)["\'])*)\1(?:,\s*(?<param2>\$[a-z0-9_-]+))?\);~si';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER))
    print_r($matches);
```

But as Jon notices it, this kind of pattern may be difficult to maintain. This is the reason why, i suggest to change the pattern to this:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
## definitions
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<sqc>        # content between single quotes
        (?> [^'\\]+  | \\. )* #'
        # can be written in a more efficient way, with an unrolled pattern:
        # [^'\\]*+ (?:\\. ['\\]*)*+
    )
    (?<dqc>        # content between double quotes
        (?> [^"\\]+  | \\. )* #"
    )
    (?<var>        # variable
        \$ [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+
    )
)

## main pattern
__\(
(?| " (?<param1> \g<dqc> ) " | ' (?<param1> \g<sqc> ) ' )
# note that once you define a named group in the first branch in a branch reset
# group, you don't have to include the name in other branches:
# (?| " (?<param1> \g<dgc>) " | ' ( \g<sqc> ) ' ) does the same. Even if the 
# second branch succeeds, the capture group will be named as in the first branch.
# Only the order of groups is taken in account.
(?:, \s* (?<param2> \g<var> ) )?
\);
~xs
LOD;
```

This simple change makes your pattern more readable and editable.

The *content between quotes* subpatterns have been designed to deal with escaped quotes. The idea is to match all character preceded by a backslash (that can be a backslash itself) to ensure to match literal backslashes and escaped quotes::

```
\'           # an escaped quote 
\\'        #'# an escaped backslash and a quote
\\\'         # an escaped backslash and an escaped quote
\\\\'      #'# two escaped backslashes and a quote
...
```

subpattern details:

```
(?>            # open an atomic group (inside which the bactracking is forbiden)
    [^'\\]+  #'# all that is not a quote or a backslash
  |            # OR
    \\.        # an escaped character
)*             # repeat the group zero or more times
```

Comment: thank you for that really complete response, but your  "extended version" doesn't work :/

Comment: @Asenar: I have tested the two versions and they work well. I suggest you to write: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the begining of your PHP script to find the error.

Comment: mea culpa ! it was working but I still used $match[2]  instead of $match['param1']; thanks !

Comment: @Asenar: Yes, note that when you create named subpatterns in the DEFINE zone, the number of each group changes in the main zone.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution based on my 1st expression, so I will write it, but using the extended style of Casimir, who made a really great answer

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
#
  __\(
    (?<quote>'|")  # catch the opening quote
    (?<param1>
      (?:
        [^'"]        # anything but quoteS
      |
        \\'          # escaped single quote are ok
      |
        \\"          # escaped double quote are ok too
      )*
    )
    \k{quote}             # find the closing quote
    (?:,.*){0,1}          # catch any type of 2nd parameter
  \)
#smUx               # x to allow comments :)
LOD;
```